# What kind of mineral deposit is this? Very stuck shower head

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, shower

[image: mineral deposit in part of the shower head]
[image: front facing picture of the last component]

Trying to remove and replace this very crappy shower head after noticing the water flow was strange. I manage to remove part of it but could not unscrew this base part after buying a wrench, applying/soaking with vinegar, heating it up etc. I soaked the other piece with vinegar for about 18 hours now and it has not really done anything (softened or dissolved anything). Can someone tell me the best way to remove this? I really just want to replace the shower head with a new one that has a filter

Comment: Try your photo again with proper focus. That hurts my eyes. I'd assume it's calcium. Why not just replace the shower head and nipple? Neither cost much.

Comment: @isherwood I’m trying to remove the shower head but it’s stuck. I managed to remove part of it. I’ll get more pictures as soon as I can

Comment: @isherwood I also suspected calcium but vinegar is not working at all, and there is this grey “exterior”, so I wasn’t sure

Comment: I wonder if someone used thread compound a hundred years ago and it's hardened.

Comment: What is it **exactly** that you are trying to remove? It is common for that ball on the end of the shower arm to actually be an integrated piece *of the shower arm*. In other words, that assembly is all one piece and must be removed (unthreaded) from the wall piping as a complete unit. The nut behind the ball (which is part of your shower head) cannot be removed without removing the entire arm, nor can the ball be removed from the arm. This is not always the case, but it is not uncommon.

Comment: If a chemical like CLR calcium, lime,rust resolver won't take it off I would agree with isherwood. Old fittings can be a bigger to remove, 1 wrench on the pipe one on the fitting, I use leather (old belt) to protect the chrome.